# Error deploying SharePoint 2010 solution with InfoPath form (The path is not of a legal form.)

Tags: infopath, deployment, solution-deployment

I am new to SharePoint and .Net development, sorry if answer for my question is obvious.

I've created SharePoint solution, which uses InfoPath form. When I deploy it from Visual Studio, all work fine, but when I try to deploy WSP package from web interface it fails with error:

```
[ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.]
System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck) +3806
System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor(String path) +245       
Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver.EnumerateFormTemplates(SPFeatureDefinition featureDef) +156
Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver.FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) +789
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.DoInstallationCallout(SPSite site, String solutionHash, Boolean fInstall) +27309665
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.Install(SPSite site, String solutionHash) +444
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinitionCollection.AddCore(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, SPSite site, String solutionHash, Boolean fForce, Boolean fDoValidation) +26381365
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinitionCollection.AddInternal(String relativePathToFeatureManifest, Guid solutionId, String solutionHash, SPSite site, Boolean force, Boolean fDoValidation, SPFeatureDefinitionContext featureDefinitionContext) +174
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.AddFeatureDefinitions(SPFeatureDefinitionCollection featColl, SPFeatureDefinitionContext context, Boolean force, Boolean activateFeatures, SPSite site, SPWeb web) +290
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUserCodeSolutionPackage.EnableSiteCollectionSolution(SPSite site, Int32 solutionGalleryItemId, Boolean force) +23867323
Microsoft.SharePoint.<>c__DisplayClass1.<AddOrUpgrade>b__0() +4075
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +27948246
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.AddOrUpgrade(SPListItem item, SPUserSolution existingSolution) +449
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.Add(Int32 solutionGalleryItemId) +574
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SolutionItemButton.ActivateItem() +398
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPLinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +72
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

My module Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Forms">
    <File Path="Forms\CustomTaskForm1.xsn" Url="Forms/CustomTaskForm1.xsn" />
    <File Path="Forms\CustomTaskForm0.xsn" Url="Forms/CustomTaskForm0.xsn" />
    <File Path="Forms\CustomTaskForm7.xsn" Url="Forms/CustomTaskForm7.xsn" />
    <File Path="Forms\ApproveTaskForm.xsn" Url="Forms/ApproveTaskForm.xsn" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

There is an answer to the problem [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sharepoint2010customization/thread/d648be5c-8613-494f-a7f0-9f7763710411), which tells that the error occurs then Path attrubute is incorrect, but I can't understand what directory is current and how I have to change the Path attribute. Could you help me, please?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE1:** Thanks to Kai answer, solution was found. There was an error in my Feature.Template.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <ReceiverAssembly="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"   ReceiverClass="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver">
 <Properties>
   <Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="true" />
   <Property Key="RegisterForms" Value="Forms\*.xsn"/>
 </Properties>
</Feature>
```

When I removed ReceiverAssembly element, all deploys succesfully.

**UPDATE 2:** But now I have got next question. When I deploy my solution, it deploys without errors, creates all lists , but I can't see my workflows. When I deploy it using VS2010 all works fine (workfows shown and associated with lists).

**UPDATE 3:** Actually, it doesn't work... when I remove ReceiverAssembly element it only deploys without error, but when I choose task (and InfoPath form have to start), it fails... When I change my ReceiverAssembly element how Kai shows, it deploys from VS, but not from WSP again...

**UPDATE 4:** Hurray! Now it works! Thanks to all!

Comment: For your second question, I would recommend asking a new question with the details. You can always link back to this one if you need to.

Comment: @Puhan, if you want to register your form templates in form services, you should update your feature tag with `<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="UpdateItemTitleWF" Id="7e843b56-cec3-4eeb-8c89-8a746dbf723a" ReceiverAssembly="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" ReceiverClass="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver" Scope="Site">`

Comment: When I add it, deployment fails, but without it, I can't use InfoPath forms when I deployed it by VS. Did I understood you right, that without this tag, I can't use InfoPath forms in my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Now it works. It seems like the root of the problem is [next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680544/cant-find-workflow-deployed-as-wsp-solution-when-i-deploy-it-from-vs-it-works/9682862#9682862):
I've tryed to add WSP Farm solution to sandbox solution gallery. I have to use another way for deploying, for example PowerShell.

PS: Thanks to [Balamurugan-S KAUST answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f73236e8-98e7-4a4d-a9cb-c543ab59aca9)

Answer (score 1):

As per msdn - [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo.aspx) -

> `ArgumentException` - path contains invalid characters such as ", <,> >, or |

Path in your situation is [featureDef.RootDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfeaturedefinition.rootdirectory.aspx) (by stack trace I can see that you are using `WorkflowFeatureReceiver`, so check out method `EnumerateFormTemplates` using Reflector). Check if path to your feature contain not legal characters.

Comment: Big thanks! Now it deploys without errors, but I have new question shown above, could you help me, please?